# Installing CodeDeploy Agent on EC2 Instance via User Data

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I'm looking to install the CodeDeploy agent on an EC2 instance with User Data deployed through CloudFormation.  [Here is the script I'm using from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codedeploy-agent-launch-configuration/)

However, when I place the script in the UserData property of my EC2 instance in CloudFormation, I get this error from the linter:

```
E1019 Parameter PLAT for Fn::Sub not found at Resources/Server/Properties/UserData/Fn::Base64/Fn::Sub
```

Here's the snippet:

```
UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe

          ## Code Deploy Agent Bootstrap Script##


          exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
          AUTOUPDATE=false

          function installdep(){

          if [ ${PLAT} = "ubuntu" ]; then

            apt-get -y update
            # Satisfying even ubuntu older versions.
            apt-get -y install jq awscli ruby2.0 || apt-get -y install jq awscli ruby



          elif [ ${PLAT} = "amz" ]; then
            yum -y update
            yum install -y aws-cli ruby jq

          fi

          }

          function platformize(){

          #Linux OS detection#
          if hash lsb_release; then
            echo "Ubuntu server OS detected"
            export PLAT="ubuntu"


          elif hash yum; then
            echo "Amazon Linux detected"
            export PLAT="amz"

          else
            echo "Unsupported release"
            exit 1

          fi
          }


          function execute(){

          if [ ${PLAT} = "ubuntu" ]; then

            cd /tmp/
            wget https://aws-codedeploy-${REGION}.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
            chmod +x ./install

            if ./install auto; then
              echo "Instalation completed"
                if ! ${AUTOUPDATE}; then
                      echo "Disabling Auto Update"
                      sed -i '/@reboot/d' /etc/cron.d/codedeploy-agent-update
                      chattr +i /etc/cron.d/codedeploy-agent-update
                      rm -f /tmp/install
                fi
              exit 0
            else
              echo "Instalation script failed, please investigate"
              rm -f /tmp/install
              exit 1
            fi

          elif [ ${PLAT} = "amz" ]; then

            cd /tmp/
            wget https://aws-codedeploy-${REGION}.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
            chmod +x ./install

              if ./install auto; then
                echo "Instalation completed"
                  if ! ${AUTOUPDATE}; then
                      echo "Disabling auto update"
                      sed -i '/@reboot/d' /etc/cron.d/codedeploy-agent-update
                      chattr +i /etc/cron.d/codedeploy-agent-update
                      rm -f /tmp/install
                  fi
                exit 0
              else
                echo "Instalation script failed, please investigate"
                rm -f /tmp/install
                exit 1
              fi

          else
            echo "Unsupported platform ''${PLAT}''"
          fi

          }

          platformize
          installdep
          REGION=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r ".region")
          execute
```

What am I missing here?  This script works fine in User Data when utilized creating an instance through the console.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `${}` is special for the cloudformation `Sub` function. You need to escape it with a `!` eg `${!PLAT}` (or remove the `{}` as they are not needed in the script anywhere you are using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hat tip for @jordanm's comment.  This resolved my issue.

Comment: Not very useful answer